# Django global login required middleware error

Tags: python, django, login-required

I'm using Django to make a website

In the website, users can have access to all pages only after they log in the website other than login page.

So, I did `pip install django-glrm` and added `'global_login_required.GlobalLoginRequiredMiddleware'` in `MIDDLEWARE` in `settings.py`

Here is the reference https://django-glrm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html

After installing, I just added `@login_not_required` to login function and it worked for several days.

However, today I ran into an error.

`Not Found http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/?next=/`

What is the problem?

After erasing `'global_login_required.GlobalLoginRequiredMiddleware'` in `settings.py`, it does not show the error but login required does not work of course.

Please let me know it you have an idea

Comment: Django has build in authentication system so additional modules are not required..

Comment: Check this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/

Comment: What I want to do is applying ```login_required``` to every pages other than login page.  That's why I'm using global_login_required middleware

Comment: In build-in auth also has same feature there is decorator @login_required

Comment: Yes there is. But if I use it, I have to add that decorator to all functions in ```views.py```. I don't want to do that. I just want to add ```login_not_required``` to only a few functions. Is there any way to do this?